# [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Object has been closed

Tags: sql-server-2008, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I’m migrating to Windows 2012 server and have ColdFusion 10 update 12 installed. I have a ColdFusion data source connecting to MS SQL 2008 R2 server with connection string (EncryptionMethod=SSL) on Windows 2008 R2. I'm getting the following error:

> **Error Executing Database Query.**
>
> [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Object has been closed.

I've tried restarting the ColdFusion services, rebooting web/database server but nothing seems to work. Anyone else encountered this problem? If so how did you resolve it?

Comment: Is you SQL 2008 full patched? I remember this happening a while back - this gives more information - http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2653857. I believe it was sorted in 2008 R2 SP2

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have SQL 2008 R2, 10.50.1600.1. I'll take at the link.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by updating the SQL Server 2008 to service pack 3. here is the link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2880350/en-us, hope this help others.